# Having both id and _id in Loopback4 model

Tags: mongodb, loopback, loopback4

I'm trying to query a mongodb collection with documents containing both id (a uuid) and _id (mongo generated), I defined both id and _id in the model

```
@property({
 type: 'string',
 id: true,
 generated: false,
 required: true,
})
  id: string;

@property({
   type: 'string',
   id: false,
   required: true,
})
  _id: string;
```

but can only retrieve the id mongo generated, anybody know how to get the other id ? much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use cli command `lb4 discovery`, and loopback will generate a model class based on table/view columns.